# Simple TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution Example with a Problem

Tags: optaplanner

I am currently trying to implement the Optaplanner Libraries into an easy TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution Example. My current code is trying to be as simple as possible and is using mostly default stuff like the vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SolverFactory<TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource("test/vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml");
    solverFactory.getSolverConfig();
    Solver<TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution> solver = null;
    try{
          solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    // from 12/07/2018 @ 12:00pm to 12/07/2018 @ 12:30pm
    TimeWindowedCustomer hans = new TimeWindowedCustomer();
    hans.setReadyTime(1544184000);
    hans.setDueTime(1544185800);
    // from 12/07/2018 @ 11:00pm to 12/07/2018 @ 11:30pm
    TimeWindowedCustomer detlef = new TimeWindowedCustomer();
    detlef.setReadyTime(1544180400);
    detlef.setDueTime(1544182200);

    RoadLocation hansRoad = new RoadLocation();
    RoadLocation detlefRoad = new RoadLocation();
    RoadLocation hubRoad = new RoadLocation();
    HashMap hansMap = new HashMap<RoadLocation, Double>();
    //10min
    hansMap.put(detlefRoad, 0.6);
    //15min
    hansMap.put(hubRoad, 0.9);
    hansRoad.setTravelDistanceMap(hansMap);

    HashMap detlefMap = new HashMap<RoadLocation, Double>();
    //10min
    detlefMap.put(hansRoad, 0.6);
    //20min
    detlefMap.put(hubRoad, 1.2);
    detlefRoad.setTravelDistanceMap(detlefMap);

    HashMap hubMap = new HashMap<RoadLocation, Double>();
    //15min
    hubMap.put(hansRoad, 0.9);
    //20min
    hubMap.put(detlefRoad, 1.2);
    hubRoad.setTravelDistanceMap(hubMap);

    TimeWindowedDepot hub = new TimeWindowedDepot();
    hub.setLocation(hubRoad);
    hans.setLocation(hansRoad);
    detlef.setLocation(detlefRoad);

    Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
    vehicle.setDepot(hub);

    List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    customers.add(detlef);
    customers.add(hans);

    List<Depot> depots = new ArrayList<Depot>();
    depots.add(hub);

    List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    vehicles.add(vehicle);

    List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    locations.add(hansRoad);
    locations.add(detlefRoad);
    locations.add(hubRoad);

    hans.setId(1L);
    detlef.setId(2L);
    hub.setId(3L);
    vehicle.setId(4L);
    hansRoad.setId(5L);
    detlefRoad.setId(6L);
    hubRoad.setId(7L);


    TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution problem = new TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution();
    problem.setCustomerList(customers);
    problem.setDepotList(depots);
    problem.setVehicleList(vehicles);
    problem.setLocationList(locations);
    problem.setDistanceType(DistanceType.ROAD_DISTANCE);

    TimeWindowedVehicleRoutingSolution solution = solver.solve(problem);

    for(Customer c : solution.getCustomerList()) {
        TimeWindowedCustomer tc = (TimeWindowedCustomer) c;
        System.out.println(tc.getArrivalTime());
    }


}
```

The Problem I am now facing is that the timewindow isn't really considered a hard rule and therefor the suggested route arrives before the timewindow. I think I am just missing breaks that the drivers could make and from looking at the code I would think that breaks are possible, just not with my configuration. So the question would be, how to get breaks into my example.

Comment: Lunch breaks are best handled in the arrival updating listener:
if the the previous arrival time was before 12:00 and this one's is after or equal to 12:00, then add a lunch break of 60 minutes.

Comment: Ok yes but I meant breaks that aren't planed for, but necessary to fit the timewindows of the following customers. In my example the first window is from 11 to 11:30 and the second from 12 to 12:30 but driving from one to the other only takes 10 minutes. Now the solution says the driver arrives at 11 at the customer and at 11:10 at the second customer, which is outside of the timewindow